# Firefox 5/6 (XPsp3) shows UTF8 inconsistensies in Wiktionary

Tags: utf-8, firefox

The following 2 pages are UTF8 encoded.

If I go to http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ahem

in the left language column I see for the Malaysian page only square "you do not have this font installed" entities

[image]

which suggests to me I am missing a font, however if I click on it, I go to http://my.wiktionary.org/wiki/ahem and I see

[image]

but all titles (mouseovers) again have the square

[image]

Can you think of why this is happening? Wrong encoding or do I need some font pack?

Safari 5 shows the same as Fx, IE8 shows only squares everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In parts of the CSS of the Malaysian site, the font "Myanmar3" was explicitly named and the following code

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Myanmar3";
    src: local("Myanmar3"), url("http://mywebfont.appspot.com/font/myanmar3.ttf");
}
```

loaded it as a web font.

IE8 does not support web fonts so all you see are squares.

Comment: Thanks! I asked this on the 4th of July with 0 answers and just changed the tag a few minutes ago :)

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)